# Angular 5 : Lazy Loading is not working properly with ng build - -prod with Angular-CLI 1.7.x

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I'm working under :

- Angular: **5.2.6**
- Angular-CLI : **1.7.x**

I have this routing file under my app *(where i ve some lazy loading modules )* :

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
        ....
      {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: 'app/home/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
        canActivate: [AuthGuardAdmin]
      },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

Whle running **ng serve** , the lazy loading did not work , and i get this error :

```
>     core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function
>     TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Whith some googling i was told to change my lazy loading like this :

```
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: ()=> AdminModule,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardAdmin]
  },
```

this works in **development mode** **:)**  , but when running ng **build --prod** , it fails again throwing this :

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'HomeRoutingModule'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'ɵ0'
    'ɵ0' contains the error at app/home/home-routing/home-routing.module.ts(182,23)
      Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
```

So i'm afraid that i'm not able to get it work.

I  don t want to downgrade **angular-cli to 1.6.x**  for some other reasons .

**So any ideas of how to fix it ??**

Comment: what `typescript` version do you use? Try `2.6.2`

Comment: @messerbill , i am using 2.4.2

Comment: This: `loadChildren: ()=> AdminModule` won't work for lazy loading (or AOT). Stick to your original syntax and let's figure out why that is causing an error.

Comment: Can you post a duplication repo, I can't duplicate with the code posted

Comment: @firasKoubaa does changing to version `2.6.2` not work?

Comment: @messerbill even 2.6.2 the same problem persists

Comment: I'm just facing the same problem! any solution?

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue with lazy loading, any fixes for this problem??

Comment: no solutions yet

Comment: running the command with aot (-aot) flag works for me. But im still looking for a solution so i dont need to develop in -aot mode.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite apparent.

For me it was to remove the lazy loaded module import in app.module. Since it should be lazy loaded this makes sense. 
Found the solution to this somewhere in this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9488
Works with cli version > 1.7.x

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,
    // custom modules
    AppRoutingModule,
    HeaderModule,
    LoginModule,
    Feature1Module, <!-- this is my lazyLoaded module // remove this line
    ConceptModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, AuthStoreService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: This totally helped me, I had forgotten to stop importing my "lazy" module in the app component.